# Loading camera roll images in iOS GridView very slow

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, alassetslibrary, aqgridview

I am showing all the images from the camera roll in my iPhone app. I build an array of `ALAsset *` that contains the list of all images in the camera roll when the app starts. I form cells by loading these images in a image view:

```
// Get the full resolution image for asset
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation]; 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRep fullResolutionImage]];
[cell.imageCropper setImage:image];
```

I do this when a new cell is requested in

```
- (AQGridViewCell *) gridView: (AQGridView *) aGridView cellForItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index
```

The problem is that it lags when there are many images and the user scrolls quickly through the images. What is the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider loading the images in the background using GCD.
Maybe this helps: [loading images from a background thread using blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502073/loading-images-from-a-background-thread-using-blocks/7502281#7502281)

Answer (score 1):

Use thumbnail instead of fullResolutionImages

Comment: Thumbnail was too small for the app that I was working on. I ended up using `fullScreenImage` with background loading as suggested by @HeikoG.