# Run code in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, background-process

I'm trying to download an image from a website and save it as a UIImage but if the user has low connection this can take forever... how can I download it in the background so the user can keep using the app in the meantime?

here is the code:

```
theIcon.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWebsite.com/Icon.png"]]];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502073/loading-images-from-a-background-thread-using-blocks

Comment: @Vjy Which answer do you refer to?

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL:` will not work reliable (if at all) for accessing remote resources. You should use either the asynchronous convenient method from class `NSURLConnection` or use it in asynchronous style and implement the delegates.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper What's wrong with dataWithContentsOfURL? It's worked fine on all my apps in the past, I'd hate to have to go update them all haha! /:

Comment: It's for use with _file_ URLs. That it works for remote URLs may be by accident, bad luck, or by mistake. It's unreliable and not appropriate for remote resources. Be careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GCD.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // do my background code
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // do handling on main thread when done!
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked amazingly for the image, but when I tried to do it with text the app crashed... Here is the code I used (It works in the main thread, just not in your GCD code area) `advertisementTitle.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myWebsite.com/OneParagraph.html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];`

Comment: This was the error log: `Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...`

Comment: (*Note: I'm using ARC)

Comment: It worked when I stored *NSStrings in the "background code" region and then in the "main thread when done" region I set the IBOutlet UI stuff equal to those NSStrings! God bless :)

Comment: @Nicholas Hart The question deserves more details. This answer is simply too vague, and naively applying this idiom to the OPs problem would produce incorrect, or at least suboptimal code.

Comment: The original code was a vaguely worded "how do I run code in the background."  It has since been edited to be specific to loading images.  But thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Albert: you can only call UIKit methods from the main thread.

Comment: @Nicholas Hart, I feel bad -- really. But you can edit your answer, too. I'm sure you get upvotes when you show how to use `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode and demonstrate the implementation of the principal delegates.

Comment: LOL, it's ok.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:
                       [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"] 
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the selector in background thread while the main foreground thread runs.

```
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadFile) withObject:nil];

 - (void) downloadFile {
   //download file 
   //you can show UIAlertView when done
    }
```

In your - (void) downloadFile you can download this big file.
and have an activity indicator show (or not). You can have the activity Indicator become not hidden or hidden and have it startAnimating and stopAnimating will make it spin and stop. This can be referenced from the foreground and background processes.

Comment: Thanks! Testing now! (p.s. I did NOT downvote you!)

Comment: Thanks for not downvoting me. This should work for your purposes. I've used it primarily for loading UIWebView content on pages, and downloading big files from UIWebView hyperlinks to the local documents folder in iOS.

Comment: i changed the downloadFile a little bit, too.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** -[ViewController downloadFile:])'`

Comment: I changed the downloadFile in the selector, remove the colon :

Comment: Brilliant! Haha! Running now :)

Comment: lol, yeah it should be downloadFile not downloadFile:, my bad

Comment: You should throw up a UIAlertView or something when the file is done downloading or something that indicates to the user that the process has completed :)

Comment: You can't call UIKit methods from a background thread.

Comment: Got the error: `Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...`

Comment: I'm sure that's because of what @NicholasHart just said. /: Going to attempt GCD now.

Comment: it may be conflicting. For my download app I wrote in the appstore, it allows me to performSelector in background, and download files to the documents directory and then display messages.

Comment: I suppose you can download the file to your NSDcouments directory, and load it when it's ready, but the background thread has to send a notification message to the foreground or main thread,.

Comment: do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905192/iphone-grand-central-dispatch-main-thread

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way:

```
NSMutableRequest* request = ... ;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error) {
    if (!error) {
        // do something with the response data.    
    }
}];
```

This approach is sufficient for "a prove of concept", toy programs with simplistic insecure connections, Apple samples, and for hobbyists learning iOS for fun, and for samples which demonstrate anti-patterns ("How you should do it, not!").

If you want a solid approach you need to use `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode and implement the delegates - or use a third party library. ;)